# How do I detect if stdout is connected to a tty in Perl?

Tags: perl, stdout, tty

I'm looking for the Perl equivalent to this Python code:

```
from sys import stdout
if stdout.isatty():
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [-t filetest operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

```
print -t STDOUT ? "Yes\n" : "No\n"
```

Note that in Perl, STDOUT can be tied (essentially an overcomplicated overloaded object) so output to STDOUT may still reach a TTY even if its not directly attached to one.

Comment: IO::Interactive shows the special cases that you may want to consider too.

Comment: How on Earth does this answer have a score of +5, while another (earlier!) post with *exactly* the same answer has a score of -1 ?

Comment: @Evgeny That answer was originally `print -t 1 ? "yes\n" : "no\n"`.  The unnecessary use of a fileno bought it downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Use [IO::interactive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Interactive) if you require STDOUT to actually be connected to the terminal, and not just being redirected to `/dev/null/` or whatever.